# How to reduce $\overline{K} \leq L$, or how to show semi-decidability of a given language?

Tags: reductions, undecidability, halting-problem, semi-decidability

I'm currently preparing for an exam and I'm having trouble to solve the following Questions.

> Let $w \in \{0,1\}^*$ and let $L$ be a language defined as follows
> $$L = \{w \mid \mathsf{time}_{M_w}(x) \leq |x| +1 \text{ for all words } x\}$$
>
> 1. *Is $L$ co-semi-decidable?*
> 2. *Is $L$ semi-decidable?*

For the first question, I think the answer is *yes*, since we can use dove-tailing to find at least one word that isn't in $L$.

I think the answer for the second question is *no*, and therefore I've tried to show $\overline{K} \leq L$, where we denote $\overline{K}$ as the special haltingproblem, defined as follows $$\overline{K} = \{w \mid M_w \text{ doesn't halt on }w\}$$

But exactly that is where I'm having trouble. I can't seem to find the right reduction function. Any help is appreciated!